# Homepage won't show newly added records but other pages do

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I'm using a Laravel 5.7 in an old web project last year 2019 but now I encountered a very weird bug.
This is a website that when you add a new game, it will show to the menu list and if it is featured it will show to the homepage content.

this is the table `['game_id', 'name', 'key', 'status', 'order', 'is_featured']`

in the header view I put this code:

```
<ul class="nav-menu">
          <li class="{{ ($page == "games" ? 'menu-active' : '') }} submenu dropdown"><a href="/games" >Games</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
               @foreach(GetPublishedGames() as $game)
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="/games/{{$game->key}}">{{$game->name}}</a></li>
               @endforeach
            </ul>
          </li>
...
```

calling this helper code `GetPublishedGames()`

```
function GetPublishedGames(){
        $data = DB::table("game")->where("status", 1)->orderBy("order")->get();
        return $data;
    }
```

in the homepage controller I had this line 
`"feat_games" => Game::where("status", 1)->where("is_featured", 1)->orderBy("order")->limit(5)->get(),`

that calls in the homepage view:

```
@if(count($feat_games))
              @foreach($feat_games as $feat_game)
                <div class="feat-game-item wow fadeInUp">
                  ... some content ...
                </div>
              @endforeach
            @endif
```

I have no idea why this happening, it works before in the local and development stage. I did tried to clear cache.

any idea?

Comment: if you remove `->limit(5)` ,does the new records shows?

Comment: it shows the record but not the newly added one

Comment: to debug the error please make sure:
(1. the record is really exist in the database)
(2. `status` AND `is_featured` of the new record = `1`)

Comment: well, the record exist in the backend and in the other pages.. except in the homepage. weird thing is, they had the same code.